# error table1 is not associated with table2 cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp, associations

email_orgs has relationship many-one with organizations

Tabel email_orgs

```
id   |  name  | organizations_id

1    |  a     | 1

2    |  b     | 1

3    |  c     | 2

4    |  d     | 3
```

Table organizations

```
id   |  name  

1    |  aa     

2    |  bb    

3    |  cc
```

Model email_orgs

```
class email_orgsTable extends table
{    
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {       
        $this->table('email_orgs');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('organizations', [
            'foreignKey' => 'organizations_id', 
            'joinType' => 'INNER',          
            'className' => 'organizations',         
        ]);
    }
```

}

Model organizations

```
class organizationsTable extends table
{       
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {       
        $this->table('organizations');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('tabaghe_organizations_peoples', [
            'foreignKey' => 'tabagheOrganizationsPeople_id', 
            'joinType' => 'INNER',          
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('onvane_organizations', [
            'foreignKey' => 'onvaneOrganizations_id', 
            'joinType' => 'INNER',          
        ]);         
    }
}
```

Controller

```
    $email_org=TableRegistry::get('email_orgs');
    $email_org=$email_org->find('all')->contain(['organizations'])->offset($from)->limit($to) ;
```

say erro "email_orgs is not associated with organizations"

please help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Model and Database Conventions

Table class names are plural and CamelCased. People, BigPeople, and ReallyBigPeople are all examples of conventional model names.

Table names corresponding to CakePHP models are plural and underscored. The underlying tables for the above mentioned models would be people, big_people, and really_big_people, respectively.

You can use the utility library Cake\Utility\Inflector to check the singular/plural of words. See the Inflector for more information.

Field names with two or more words are underscored: first_name.

Foreign keys in hasMany, belongsTo or hasOne relationships are recognized by default as the (singular) name of the related table followed by _id. So if Bakers hasMany Cakes, the cakes table will refer to the bakers table via a baker_id foreign key. For a table like category_types whose name contains multiple words, the foreign key would be category_type_id.

Join tables, used in BelongsToMany relationships between models, should be named after the model tables they will join, arranged in alphabetical order (apples_zebras rather than zebras_apples).

[conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html)

Answer (score 2):

Really silly.

i do not know but when rename `email_orgs` to `emailorgs` in database and model

this worked.

i do not know why??